# Computing regression between different groups

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have four groups of Age data changing with altitude. I need to do the linear regression between different groups according to altitude . I wonder if using just lm is meaning for my case.

```
Altitude Age
100     22
100     24 
100     35
200     41
200     24
200     14
300    25
300     18
300     25

model<- lm(Age~Altitude, data=DF)
summary(model1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "regression between different groups according to altitude" and  "if using just lm is meaning for my case"? Could you clarify and provide better example?

Comment: Where is altitude in your data? What exactly is "Age" here?

Comment: I edited my question. I need to know if the age is changing with altitude in a linear trend or not?

Comment: Then linear regression will work in this case.

Comment: You can just make simple scatter plot to see the relationship and add regression line to it.

Comment: set altitude a factor and run a simple lm(), since you mentioned altitude to be groups.

Comment: @KaleesWaran, thank you for your answer. yes altitude is defining the groups but i need to see how the age will change with changing altitude, so i think that i should not set it as factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Altitude <- factor(rep(c(100, 200, 300), each = 3))
Age <- c(22, 24, 35, 41, 24, 14, 25, 18, 25)
df <- data.frame(Altitude, Age)
```

You can check the p-value of the significance of the Altitude factor.

```
model <- lm(Age ~ Altitude, data = df)
summary(model)
```

Or you can just see it on a boxplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Altitude, y = Age)) + geom_boxplot()
```